# how to convert data to observable collection

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I'm working with a database structure like this:

```
item_id     int
list_name   string
category_name   string
item_name   string
qty     int
price       double
total_amt   double
```

i am trying to get item list according to category..(group by & sum)

```
private ObservableCollection<shoppingitem> _purchased;
public ObservableCollection<shoppingitem> Purchased
{
    get
    {
        return _purchased;
    }
    set
    {
        _purchased = value;
        notifypropertychanged("Purchased");
    }
}

public void  budgetcategorywise()
{
     var q = from shoppingItem p in db.Item1
               group p by p.category_name into g
               select new { category = g.Key, total = g.Sum(p => p.total_amt) };

     Purchased=new ObservableCollection<shoppingitem>(q);
}
```

it is giving error of type casting.
now the problem is how i should bind this result to listbox.
it requires conversion..?

i need to convert the result in an ObservableCollection to bind with listbox..

Comment: Why do you need an ObservableCollection for a list that (I think) is not going to change?

Answer (score 2):

You should return the collection of `shoppingitem`, not an anonymous type!

Just replace the `select new` with `select new shoppingitem` and it should work fine!

Comment: Or, since p is already a shoppingitem, you can just `select p`

Answer (score 0):

You group over `shoppingItem`s and you try to return the *aggregated* result as a list of `shoppingItem`s. It is correct that you should return a named type in the collection, but I don't think it should be `shoppingItem`. Just use a simple class to transfer the results. Like

```
class ShoppingItemSumDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```